# Extraer datos de codigo HTLM a un label

Tags: vb.net

Intentare ser lo mas explicito posible.

Estoy intentando extraer el valor del dolar actual y ponerlo en un label, buscando por Internet encontré varios códigos que hacen cosas similares pero usan como filtro la etiqueta de la clase lo cual a mi no me sirve porque yo estoy intentando sacar información de una tabla, no entiendo mucho htlm y como se compone, este es el código que tengo hasta ahora para la extraccion de datos.

```
    Private Sub cargarPagina()
        web = New WebBrowser() ' Se instancia el WebBrower
        web.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True ' Oculta la ventana de errores si algún script de la página falló (de todas formas no los necesitamos)
    web.Navigate(New Uri("http://www.bna.com.ar/Personas")) ' Carga la página web creando un nuevo documento HTML

    ' Este Handler permite continuar con el proceso una vez que se ha cargado TODA la página (ya que si no ha cargado lanzará un error)
    AddHandler web.DocumentCompleted, New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf cargarValorDolar)
    End Sub

Private Sub cargarValorDolar()

    If (web.Document IsNot Nothing) Then ' En caso de que la página no halla cargado bien el documento
        Dim divs = web.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("td") ' Obtiene todos los elementos <div> de la página web

        For Each div As HtmlElement In divs ' Recorre la lista de elementos <div>
            Dim className As String = div.GetAttribute("className") ' Obtiene el atributo [class] (nos servirá de filtro)
            If className = "tit" Then ' El texto con el que se compara es el que muestra el valor del dólar en pesos argentinos
                MsgBox(div.InnerText) ' Se obtiene el valor del dólar

            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Logre extraer información pero no la que necesito

La pagina es

http://www.bna.com.ar/Personas

La información que quiero sacar es el dolar actual de hoy para la compra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código de la pagina

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="billetes">

            <table class="table cotizacion">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th class="fechaCot">21/2/2019</th>
                    <th>Compra</th>
                    <th>Venta</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                        <tr>
                        <td class="tit">Dolar U.S.A</td>
                        <td>38,6000</td> <---- Este es el dato que quiero extraer.
                        <td>40,4000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td class="tit">Euro</td>
                        <td>45,0000</td>
                        <td>47,0000</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td class="tit">Real *</td>
                        <td>980,0000</td>
                        <td>1080,0000</td>
                        </tr>

                </tbody>
                </table>       
                <a href="#" class="link-cotizacion" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalHistorico" id="buttonHistoricoBilletes">Ver histórico</a>
                <div class="legal">Hora Actualización: 15:06</div>
                <div class="legal">(*) cotización cada 100 unidades.</div>    

        </div>
```

El código que tengo es un código que encontré en otro post e intente adaptarlo al mio pero solo consigo extraer información irrelevante para mi proposito.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que sería mas sencillo que usases algun api gratuita, como por ejemplo https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/. Si insiste en el web scraping, echa un vistazo a [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/)

Comment: Lo pensé en un momento pero el precio del dolar mayorista no me sirve en este caso y todas las api de ese estilo utilizan el dolar mayorista para mi desgracia

Comment: Dentro de cargaValorDolar, web es distinto de null? o es null? Igual esto es mucho mas facil si lees todo como un gran string, y buscas exactamente la parte que queres...

Comment: ¿has probado a hacer un loop en `web.Document.QuerySelectorAll("td")`? La segunda opción dentro de ese bucle es el número que quieres, si no me equivoco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He creado un formulario con los controles `WebBrowser1`, `Button1` y `Label1`. Utilizando `HtmlAgilityPack`, es tan simple como esto:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim document = New HtmlDocument()
    Dim wsSource As String

    wsSource = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml
    document.LoadHtml(wsSource)

    Dim htmlBody As HtmlNode = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='table cotizacion']//tr//td[2]")
    Dim htmlValues As String = htmlBody.InnerText

    Label1.Text = htmlValues
End Sub
```

`wbSource` = Obtiene y almacena el código fuente cargado previamente en el control `WebBrowser`.

`document` = Carga el código fuente obtenido previamente

`htmlBody` = Recorre el código hasta el nodo indicado

`htmlValues` = Almacena el atributo `InnerText` obtenido tras el parseo previo con `htmlBody`

`//table[@class='table cotizacion']//tr//td[2]`: Busca la clase `table cotizacion` de cualquier etiqueta `<table>`, accede a la primera etiqueta `<tr>` que encuentra y recupera el valor del segundo `<td>`, que resulta ser el valor esperado.